# How much will rolling bodies like cylinders set on a surface of a fast moving body attenuate its friction with atmosphere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, rotation, speed

A car, train or a spacecraft feels a certain drag when moving through the atmosphere. I think that rolling bodies produce less drag, and hence, my question is why rolling bodies as little spheres or cylinders are not placed on the vehicle surface to reduce resistive forces. Is it that they produce more friction? why/ why not?

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm not sure how curvature effects drags.

Comment: The air must still be pushed out from in front of the car

Comment: @Krešimir Bradvica   +1 it's an interesting question.

Comment: Immagine a F1 bolid with little rolling spheres on it....  Maybe they would produce a lot of noise....

Comment: @Krešimir Bradvica yeah u are right. I tried to give something which you didn't mention in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the  other effects  but one thing can be surely said  that the rolling spheres or cylinders will experience the  [Magnus effect](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect%23:%7E:text%3DThe%2520Magnus%2520effect%2520is%2520an,the%2520object%2520is%2520not%2520spinning.&ved=2ahUKEwifvcqf9uDrAhVMILcAHVMgCd8QFjAPegQICxAH&usg=AOvVaw2ae2P97LQRe-mbV0xw9L4I)  , which can lead to unnecessary forces on the car , train or your spaceship. The Magnus force due to each of  those spheres or cylinders will produce a greater net force which can  can have dangerous effects [like this one.](https://m.imgur.com/Wh3ly0b)

To stop this from happening, we will need additional inputs. So it is better to use the former one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Krešimir Bradvica was that helpful ?

Comment: I was thinking about very small,low density cylinders...why should they cause such a strong effect?I am pretty shure that these cylinders should take away some friction while rotating synchronised with the air...